# How to write Conditional regex?

Tags: reactjs, regex, validation, yup

I want to use Yup for validation. in a part of validation I have

`const validationSchema = Yup.object({password: Yup.string().matches(passwordRegex, "passRegex")})`

passWordRegex is a varibale that contains a regex :

`const passwordRegex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{4,32}$/;`

I have some booleans that determine that if for example small letter or big letter or speciall character is needed in password or not:

```
smallLetter = false
capitalLetter = true
specialChar = true
```

now my regex ( passwordRegex variable) is not conditional . how can I write a regex (passwordRegex variable) conditional base on my Boolean variables

Comment: How many boolean conditions do you have?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have 5 : 
 Small characters required
Capital characters required
Numeric characters required
Special characters required
 Required characters

Answer (score 0):

You could build the regex string you want and then create a proper `RegExp` object:

```js
var input = "aB@3";
var smallLetter = false;
var capitalLetter = true;
var specialChar = true;
var number = true;

var regex = "";
if (smallLetter) regex += "(?=.*[a-z])";
if (capitalLetter) regex += "(?=.*[A-Z])";
if (specialChar) regex += "(?=.*[@$!%*?&])";
if (number) regex += "(?=.*[0-9])";

regex = "^" + regex + "[A-Za-z0-9@$!%*?&]{4,32}$";
var re = new RegExp(regex);
if (re.test(input)) {
    console.log(input + " => valid");
}
```